# Kivy set screen focus

Tags: kivy, label

I am trying to create an App in Kivy along with Python that contains a long scrollable list of text. Inside of this list would be Labels some of which are just headers and some of which contain the text body. My question is, is there a way to have a selectable portion of the text in a Label that on press would set the screen focus to a desired other Label? I have found ways on how to hyperlink specific text to a webpage but not a great way to set the screen focus inside of the same app instead.

i.e.:

```
<SecondWindow@ScrollView>
    name:"Page"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:(1,1,1,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            ScrollView:
                GridLayout:
                    cols:1
                    size_hint_y:None
                    size_hint:1,None
                    height:self.minimum_height
                Label:
                    name:"PrefaceL1"
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba:(109/255.0,114/255.0,219/255.0,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    text_size:self.width,None
                    text:'  Preface'
                    font_size:'52sp'

                Label:
                    name:"PrefaceB1"
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba:(1,1,1,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    text_size:self.width,None
                    text:"Long [KEY WORD SOMEWHERE IN HERE] Text"  <--------  
                    color: 0,0,0,1
                    font_size:'16sp'
                Label:
                    name:"PrefaceL2" <--------- Location of desired screen focus.
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba:(0,0,0,1)
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.pos
                            size:self.size
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]
                    text_size:self.width,None
                    text:'  Preface'
                    font_size:'52sp'

                    font_size:'16sp'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Kivy docs
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_y

You can focus on the `Label` you want by  `do_scroll_y` to the value of `desired_label.y / layout_of_the_scroll_view.height`

Comment: I think i'm onto something but now the issue is when I set the desired_label.y / layout_of_the_scroll_view.height it is saying my Label name is undefined. The Label "desired_label.y" is undefined. The Label is assigned a name during the creation of that Label but it seems now to be unable to find it? (the desired_label.y is for continuity of the demonstration)